# minifing output content of web page

Tags: php, php-5.3

I want to minify my web page content before printing them.

there are some `ob_()` functions and I'm trying to minify like this:

```
ob_start(); //first line
.
.
.
$_outPut = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo preg_replace("/([\r\n]|[\s]{2,})/","",$_outPut);
```

the output is completely fine but I want to know is there any thing that I should consider to guarantee my page from unexpected errors?

the page contains html and inline css, some times js and jquery also.

Comment: In terms of optimisation, you should take care of removing inline CSS, before than dealing with HTML.

Comment: This is my first Effort and I'm very satisfied with the result, but I know there might be something not right.

Comment: You should implement some kind of cache in order to prevent execute that operation too frequently. But the great thing of minifying is overall for JS files, you can save lot of space with good software like https://code.google.com/p/minify/